# If $R$ is commutative then $\operatorname{Hom}_R(R,M)$ is isomorphic with $R$-module $M$. Is the converse also true?

Tags: linear-algebra, ring-theory, modules, module-isomorphism

I'm reading *Elements of
Abstract and Linear Algebra* by E.H. Connell and I'm wondering if the converse of the following theorem is true (p.71):

> **Theorem** Suppose $M=M_R$ and $f,g: R\to M$ are homomorphism with $f(\underline{1})=g(\underline{1})$. Then $f=g$. Further, if $m\in M$, $\exists!$ homomorphism $h:R\to M$ with $h(\underline{1})=m$. In other words, $\operatorname{Hom}_R(R,M)\approx M$.
>
> **Proof** Suppose $f(\underline{1}) = g(\underline{1})$. Then $f(r)=f(\underline{1}\cdot r) = f(\underline{1})r=g(\underline{1})r= g(\underline{1}\cdot r) = g(r)$. Given $m\in M$, $h: R \to M$ defined by $h(r)=mr$ is a homomorphism. Thus evaluation at $\underline{1}$ gives a bijection from $\operatorname{Hom}_R(R,M)$ to $M$, and this bijection is clearly a group isomorphism. If $R$ is commutative, it is an isomorphism of $R$-modules.

Based on the comment in the proof of this theorem I believe the converse is only true for commutative rings.

**Proposition**
Suppose $M$ is an abelian group and $R$ is a commutative ring, and $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(R,M)$ the set of all group homomorphisms. If the evaluation $\Phi:\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(R,M), f\mapsto f(\underline{1})$ is a group isomorphism then $M$ can be made into a $R$-module.

*Proof.*
As $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(R,M)$ is an abelian group under pointwise addition we define a scalar multiplication to make it an $R$-module as $ f\cdot r: R\to M, s\mapsto f(rs)
$.

1. $f\cdot r$ is a group homomorphism:  $(f\cdot r)(s + t) = f(r(s+t))=f(rs+rt)=f(rs)+f(rt)=(f\cdot r)(s)+(f\cdot r)(t)$
2. Distributivity with respect to group addition in $M$  $((f_1+f_2)\cdot r)(s) =(f_1+f_2)(rs) = f_1(rs)+f_2(rs)= (f_1 \cdot r)(s) + (f_2 \cdot r)(s) = (f_1 \cdot r + f_2 \cdot r)(s) $
3. Distributivity with respect to ring addition
   $(f\cdot(r_1+r_2)(s)=f((r_1+r_2)s)=f(r_1s+r_2s)=f(r_1s +r_2s)=f(r_1s)+f(r_2s)=(f\cdot r_1)(s)+(f\cdot r_2)(s)=(f\cdot r_1+f\cdot r_2)(s)$
4. Compatibility of scalar multiplication
   $(f\cdot(r_1 r_2))(s)=f(r_1 r_2 s)=f(r_1(r_2 s))=(f\cdot r_1)(r_2 s)=((f\cdot r_1) \cdot r_2)(s)$
5. Identity of scalar multiplication
   $(f\cdot \underline{1})(s)=f(\underline{1}s)=f(s)$

We define scalar multiplication in $M$ via bijection $\Phi$ as $m\cdot r = (\Phi^{-1}(m) \cdot r)(\underline{1})$ that turns a group homomorphism $f\in \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(R, M)$ to a $R$-module homomorphism. One needs to show $f(ar)=f(a)\cdot r$. From the bijectivity of $\Phi$ there exisits a unique $g$ such that $g(\underline{1})=f(a)$ on the other hand $(f\cdot a)(\underline{1})=f(a\underline{1})=f(a)$ and $g=f\cdot a)$. Therefore $f(a)\cdot r = ((f\cdot a)\cdot r)(\underline{1})= (f \cdot (ar))(\underline{1})=f(ar\underline{1})=f(ar)$. $\blacksquare$

Question, I don't see commutativity of $R$ being used in my proof. Is something wrong with the proposed proposition?

**Edit 1**
I've improved the notation to distinguish between the set of all group homomorphisms and the set of all $R$-module homomorphisms.

**Edit 2**
I'm exploring the definition of a $R$ module. A scalar multiplication defines a ring homomorphism from the $R$ into the endomorphism ring of the group $M$.$$\Psi: R \to \operatorname{End}(M), r \mapsto \Psi(r):M\to M, m \to m\cdot r.$$

So defining a scalar multiplication amounts to defining an ring endomorphism.

On the other hand a scalar multiplication defines a group homomorphism:
$$\tilde{\Phi}: M \to \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(R,M), m\mapsto \tilde{\Phi}(m):R\to M, r \mapsto m\cdot r$$

I'm trying to characterise a scalar multiplication in terms of this type of mapping.

**Edit 3** (2022-10-16)
After having read replies to
[Why is $\operatorname{Hom}(M,N)$ not necessarily an $R$ module?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/637807/why-is-operatornamehomm-n-not-necessarily-an-r-module) the comment in the original proof that requires $R$ to be commutative is too strong. In general the following is true:

**Theorem** Suppose $R$ is a ring. Suppose $M$ is a $R$-bimodule and $N$ is a right $R$-module. Then the set of all right $R$-linear maps $\operatorname{Hom}_R(M,N)$ is a right $R$-module with scalar multiplication given by $f\cdot r : M \to N, m\mapsto f(rm)$.

Since every ring $R$ is a $(R,R)$-bimodule the *left action* of $R$ on $R$ induces a *right action* of $R$ on $\operatorname{Hom}_R(R,M)$ via $ f\cdot r: R\to M, s\mapsto f(rs) $. To check that this defines right $R$-module on  $\operatorname{Hom}_R(R,M)$ one needs to check that $f\cdot r$ is a right $R$-linear:

$$ (f\cdot r)(s a) = f(r s a) = f(r s) a = (f \cdot r)(s) a.$$

The calculations analogical to 1-5 above check remaining axioms.

The evaluation at $\underline{1}$, $\Phi:\operatorname{Hom}_{R}(R,M), f\mapsto f(\underline{1})$, is right $R$-linear as well

$$ \Phi(f\cdot r) = (f \cdot r) (\underline{1}) = f(r\underline{1}) = f(r) = f(\underline{1} r) = f(\underline{1})r = \Phi(f)r.$$

Therefore it is an isomorphism of $R$-modules in general case.

**Theorem** Suppose $R$ is a ring and $M=M_R$ is a right $R$-module. Then $\operatorname{Hom}_R(R,M)$ is a right $R$-module isomorphic to $M$.

This can be easily extended to following

**Theorem** Suppose $R$ is a ring and $M=M_R$ is a right $R$-module. Then $\operatorname{Hom}_R(R^n,M)$ is a right $R$-module isomorphic to $M^n$.

Now there is no surprise then that the proof of my proposition does not use commutativity of $R$. I agree that the proposition itself is not particularly interesting.

**Edit 4** (2022-12-23) I've changed $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbf{Grp}}(R,M)$ to a more standard notation $\operatorname{Hom}_\mathbb{Z}(R,M)$.

Comment: What does $\operatorname{Hom}_R(R,M)$ mean if $M$ is not already an $R$-module?

Comment: @JeremyRickard Good catch! I've made corrections to remove the subscript $R$ and replaced it with $\mathbf{Grp}$ when I mean it to be only the set of all group homomorphisms.  Hopefully, now the claim of the proposition is clearer that it can only be made to be eventually the set of $R$-homomorphisms.

Comment: But does your hypothesis ever happens in practice when $R$ is not $\mathbb{Z}$?

Answer (score 1):

I think your statement is a little weird. A much easier statement is this: if $R$ is any ring and $M$ an abelian group, then $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(R,M)$ is a left $R$-module through $(r\cdot f)(x)=f(xr)$, and also a right $R$-module with $(f\cdot r)(x)=f(rx)$. When $R$ is commutative these structures are equal.

Then of course, if $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(R,M)$ happens to be isomorphic to $M$ (that seems rare, but why not), you can transfer these module structures to $M$.

Comment: Every abelian group is a $\mathbb{Z}$-module. I'm trying to find an answer to the question when $M$ can be turned to a $R$-module. I'm looking for a characterisation of scalar multiplication in terms of a group morphism between $M$ and $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbf{Grp}}(R, M)$ similar to characterisation of scalar multiplication as a ring homomorphism from $R$ to endomorphism ring $\operatorname{End}(M)$.